# How to change div content while generating a new URL - AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

sorry for the basic question!

I currently have a website and I need a feature where the content of a div is replaced when a user clicks on a hyperlink

I've achieved this using the following:

```
<a href="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('desc','the button has been pressed')"> Click here </a> 


<script type="text/javascript"><!--
   function ReplaceContentInContainer(id,content) {
   var container = document.getElementById(id);
   container.innerHTML = content;
   }
</script>
```

However, I have 2 quick questions - the in the div once the button has been clicked is written as a string in the JS - is it possible to pass in a HTML file that has this text?

I need to make it so that the new text has a new URL - is this possible? (e.g. once a user has clicked on the button, the text is displayed and a new direct URL is available)

Comment: I just did something like this...are you restricted to javascript, or can we speak jQuery?

Comment: jQuery is fine (although my knowledge is limited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean something like this:

```
$('#my-link').on('click', function() {
  $('#my-div').load('/file_to_load.html');
  $(this).attr('href', "new_url");
});
```

If you can provide a bit more clarity, I'll refine my answer!

Here's how this works.

jQuery looks for the dom element with the id `#my-link`, then on click the function block is fired. jQUery `$.load` will load the content of that url into the div with the id `my-div`, then change the href attribute of `$(this)`, "this" being the button to "new_url".